# Django Template how to get the value of a model through the OneToOneField

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

In my Django App i have Two Models and the User model from django.contrib.auth.models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')

    def __str__(self):
        self.user.username
```

In my template i'm looping through objects of a Room list and i need to get the value avatar from UserPorfile

```
{% for room in rooms %}
<div class="roomListRoom">
    <div class="roomListRoom__header">
        <a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}" class="roomListRoom__author">
        <div class="avatar avatar--small">
           <img src="" /> <!-- This image should refer to the UserProfile linked to room.host-->
        </div>
        <span>@{{room.host.username}}</span>
        </a>
        <div class="roomListRoom__actions">
        <span>{{room.created|timesince}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can i do this? If i can, how? Can i solve this problem in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should retrive the avatar from user profile in views.py, then send to html via context.

code should be in views.py

```
avatar = request.user.userprofile.avatar 
context = {
'avatar ': avatar  
}
```

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it was far easier to the scope of my project to just change the field "host" from the class "Room" to an UserProfile and use your answer in cases that i need the avatar directly.

It is not a nice looking thing to do, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are passing rooms in a a context variable to cycle through, you should be able to refer to the URL field directly (as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models))

```
{{ room.host.avatar.url }}
```

or in your case

```
<img src="{{ room.host.avatar.url }}" />
```

As a side note, to reduce database calls, you may want to grab the host details when you select your list of rooms, eg,

```
roooms = Room.objects.filter(x=y).select_related('host')
```

Otherwise every time you look for the URL in your rooms loop, you'll need to make another db call to grab the host details.